# Delete only one item from table with multiple similar items

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to know, if I can perform such operation. I have following data arrangement in table:

```
id SessionId P_Name P_TypeId
1  abc        XYZ   5
2  abc        XYZ   5
3  abc        XYZ   5
4  abc        XYZ   5
5  abc        XYZ   5
6  abc        XYZ   5
7  abc        XYZ   5  
8  abc        XYZ   5
```

Here I have 8 similar items, but have unique Ids.

**Condition:**

From frontend i will pass `[P_TypeId] = 5` and the query will then remove only one item from the table using a delete statement. *Is this possible?*

Comment: what is 5,is it ID or P_Typeid?

Comment: @Kiran1016 see updated question, its TypeId

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, for example using `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH x 
     AS (SELECT id, 
                sessionid, 
                p_name, 
                p_typeid, 
                RN = Row_number() 
                       OVER( 
                         partition BY sessionid, p_name, p_typeid 
                         ORDER BY id) 
         FROM   dbo.tablename
         WHERE P_TypeId = @P_TypeId ) 
DELETE x 
WHERE  rn = 1
```

Deletes the lowest id of each group.

[**DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5dd15/3/1)

Answer (score 2):

```
delete top(1) from mytable where p_typeid = 5
```

The above will delete one row that contains a p_typeid of 5.

If you want to delete the row with lowest id then try

```
 with t as (
   select top(1) * from mytable where p_typeid = 5
   order by id
 )
 delete from t
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
delete from dbo.your_tablename 
where id = (select top 1 id from dbo.your_tablename where P_TypeId = 5)
```

Feels like a bit of a hack though.

As the other answers have done, you could also add a `where` clause to the `select top...` query if required.